# file not found on existing file in apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is what is strange. In my apache error_log, when google crawls my site, I receive errors that the file is not found, yet I'm able to access all valid urls normally without producing any errors in the log. I could not seem to reproduce the error myself.

Somewhere someone was suggesting the use of allowoverride all but if I use that then I'm opening up the ability to use .htaccess files which I do not want to do because I don't want hackers to break in.

Does google use any special parameters of some sort to make an attempt to access the URLs?

I make heavy use of Mod_rewrite and I always use the NC and L flags in every rule in my apache configuration.

Comment: Difficult to suggest anything without seeing your rules and some example URLs that are working for you but not for bot

Answer (score 0):

Google and others, when they crawls dynamic pages, delete session ID and others...

[Google Webmaster Guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769?hl=en&ref_topic=6002025):

> Allow search bots to crawl your sites without session IDs or arguments
>   that track their path through the site. These techniques are useful
>   for tracking individual user behavior, but the access pattern of bots
>   is entirely different. Using these techniques may result in incomplete
>   indexing of your site, as bots may not be able to eliminate URLs that
>   look different but actually point to the same page.

And if you redirect after with a missing parameter...

You can read: [Keep a simple URL structure](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/76329?hl=en)